# Idioms for "looking for something" and "trying to find something in a room full of mess"

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

I am trying to find idioms that could express "looking for something" and "trying to find something in a room full of mess". One that I could find was "hunt high and low," but for some reason I don't really feel satisfied using it. Can someone please suggest some other phrase?

I would like to use in a context like this:

> "I tried to look for the pen in my dorm room (which was messy) but couldn't find it".

For e.g. I would want to tell someone that every time I want something, I have to search the place thoroughly to locate it.

Comment: "Like looking for a needle in a haystack", "I found it in the last place I looked".

Comment: "Searching in **every nook and cranny**" means to look in every possible place for something. It doesn't require the place where you are searching to be full of mess.

Comment: There are several questions that already cover this idiom.  Have you searched the site?

Comment: I didn't know what to search for... and searching for something using the keyword "search" did not help much...

Comment: I've edited the question for a clearer explanation of what I would like to convey. For eg. I would want to tell someone that every time I want something, I have to search the place thoroughly to locate it.

Comment: @Dez so you have to *turn the room upside down*?

Comment: @Dez - this should be in an answer.

Comment: @cornbread ninja - great! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!PS: I don't know how to select that comment as the answer.

Comment: @Dez Hooray!  I will make it an answer, then.

Comment: I think as Mitch suggested in the first comment "looking for a needle in a haystack" is the best answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are not idioms, but they may be useful hyperboles:

You could say "Every time I need something from there, I need to call search-and-rescue to find it."

Or "Only a search dog can find what I need in there."

Comment: Yes, this seems to be a viable option.

Answer (score 4):

I think an expression that explains *why* you can't find an object might be more useful.
You said you tried looking for a pen in your room, which was messy, and failed.

So you could say something similar to:

"I tried looking everywhere, but the room [**looked like a bomb had hit it**](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/look%2Blike%2Ba%2Bbomb%27s%2Bhit%2Bit___1)!"

Comment: That's good but I was looking for something that would focus more on the act of searching rather than the mess in the room.

Comment: @Dez Then Mitch's suggestion, like looking for a needle in a haystack, is the one I would opt for. If he had written it as an answer. I would not have proposed this alternative.

Comment: The OD link is this: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/look-like-a-bomb's-hit-it

Answer (score 4):

"Trying to find a needle in a haystack" would work efficiently in this scenario.

Comment: "needle in a haystack" was suggested in the first comment.  It is OK to take a suggestion in a comment and expand on it in an answer, but your answer adds nothing to the comment.

Answer (score 2):

You might say,

> I tried to look for the pen in my dorm room.  **I turned the room upside down**, but never found the pen.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, with some more reading, I now realise that the word I was looking for was "rummage".
I rummaged through my room to find it.

Comment: -1 In your question you said you were looking for an idiom, but in your answer you accepted a verb.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Although "rummage" was the word I was originally looking for. I wont change the question though. Accepting another answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

I *searched high and low*; I *left no stone unturned*; I had to *go over the place with a fine-tooth comb*.

Answer (score 0):

Run it to ground is one of the best ones I can come up with. it stands for looking for someone or something until its is found and resolved to your satisfaction

Comment: Run somebody/something to earth/ ground (BrE) means to **succeed** in finding someone or something after a long search.