# Idiom or proverb describes the huge effort to be spent to find something?

Tags: idiom-requests, proverbs

For example, this idiom is a thing that I'm trying hard to find. It applies itself in this situation.

While the idiom *needle in a haystack* is pretty close, it only describes the state of being hard to find, not the effort you actually have to spend to find it. It might be easily found by most people, but not me. That thing can be an object, an job, or a coterie.

More specific, the thing I'm looking for is a **field of academic**. For a long time, I have always wanted to see myself to do a specific scientific activity. But only recently I find the exactly name of the field that I think I should work for. Without it, my academic proposal is less persuaded. I want to convey this joy of this little success into my essay. Thanks to many answers, I think *look high and low for* is what I need, since it's simple enough so that the readers won't think that I'm trying to use bombastic words.

Comment: Do you want an idiom that express the idea that "you are working hard"?  Or do you want an idiom that expresses "you are working *too* hard"?  Or do you really want to play up the fact that "what you are looking for is easily found by others but not you"?

Comment: The complete expression 'It's like looking for a needle in a haystack' obviously includes the notion of seeking.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth it is, but I want to emphasize the work I spend to find it rather than the fact that's it's rare to find

Comment: @Nick2253 just "I'm working hard to find it". It's more like to find it, you will need endurance. It may sometimes make you tired, but it won't be so hard to make you exhausted. It *may* be easy for some people to find it, not *can*. I'll edit it.

Comment: The 'looking for' does that.

Comment: Perhaps see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116940/idioms-for-looking-for-something-and-trying-to-find-something-in-a-room-full/

Comment: finding a polar bear in a snowstorm?

Comment: Not sure from your question whether this will suit, but 'Desperately seeking' is a popularly used and paraphrased term, after the usage in personal ads, and also in the film title "Desperately seeking Susan".

Comment: Can you give an example of how you want to use this?

Comment: @Barmar see my update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"[To look high and low for](http://www.sky-net-eye.com/eng/english/idioms/american/i_l/4878-look-high-and-low-for)" is an idiomatic phrase about searching everywhere, perhaps with difficulty, for something.

The only "proverb" including this phrase that I could find concerns the quest for wisdom and comes from the Bible's book of [Proverbs (14:6)](http://www.biblestudytools.com/msg/proverbs/passage.aspx?q=proverbs%2014:6-8) :

> 6. Cynics look high and low for wisdom - and never find it; the
>      open-minded find it right on their doorstep!

Comment: Can I use it in present perfect tense?

Comment: I have (I've) looked high and low for that thing.  Yeah, I think that's the present perfect and it works.  I think you can use it in/with any tense. @Ooker

Answer (score 3):

For the *object* of a difficult but earnestly prosecuted search or quest, I suggest *grail,* variously defined in on-line dictionaries as “[the object of a prolonged endeavor](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/grail)” or “[the object of an extended or difficult quest](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grail).”

Answer (score 3):

The idiom ***"eludes"*** you, or you can say it is ***"elusive"***

From [Merriam-Webster Online Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elusive):

> elusive: hard to find or capture

Answer (score 2):

There are many examples of what you are looking for.

"It's like trying to herd cats."

"Pushing water uphill with rake."

"Like beating a dead horse."

"Trying to get blood out of a stone."

Comment: The middle two refer to things that are extremely hard to do, generally, but the first is specifically about trying to get uncoöperative people to do something and the last about trying to get something from someone or something that it won't deliver. They don't seem relevant.

Comment: @JonHanna "Beating a dead horse" is not something that's hard to do.  In fact, "beating a dead horse" has nothing to do with looking for things, or things that are hard to do.  It's about continuing to bring up (generally in conversation) already resolved issues.

Comment: @Nick2253 yes, easy to do but pointless. It does make it a reasonable hypernymic phrase.